# I want to set the volume while append an audio samplebuffer to a new file with AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation

I need to copy an audio track from an asset to append to a new file.
And for some reason I need use AVAssetWriter instead of AVExportSession.
So can't use AVAudioMix to do that.
So can I do that with AVAssetWriter?

Comment: Have you tried setting preferredVolume on your AVAssetWriterInput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I can use AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput, which has a property audioMix, which can do the requirement.